# How to use spaces in json key and still be able to access in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, json, regex

i am currently having problem using key value from json and show it in accordian in angular. the key is working properly when there is no space in between and i am able to open the panel but when i add a space to make it look better i can't seem to open it.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-12">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                <div ng-repeat="key in notSorted(items) track by $index" class="panel panel-default menu-panel" ng-init="value = items[key]" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" id="menu-link" href="#{{key}}">
                    <div class="panel-heading panel-types">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                        {{key}}
      </h4>
                    </div></a>
                    <div id="{{key}}" class="panel-collapse collapsing menu-items">
                        <div ng-repeat="item in value">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-3">
                                    <p class="item-name">
                                    <span ng-if="item.itemtype=='veg'" class="fa-stack fa-lg text-success" title="Veg"> <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i> <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-1x"></i> </span>
                                    <span ng-if="item.itemtype=='nonveg'" class="fa-stack fa-lg text-danger" title="Non Veg"> <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i> <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-1x"></i></span>

                                    {{item.itemname}}
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-3">
                                    <p><i class="fa fa-inr"></i> {{item.price}}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6">


                                            <a href ng-click="rprocess(item)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></a>

                              <span ng-bind-html="item.quantity|| 0"></span>

                                            <a href ng-click="process(item)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>


                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

and here is my sample json:

```
{
 "Veg Starters": [
        {
            "itemname": "Paneer Tikka",
            "itemtype": "veg",
            "price": "110"
      },
        {
            "itemname": "Mushroom Chilly",
            "itemtype": "veg",
            "price": "90"
      },
        {
            "itemname": "Masala Papad",
            "itemtype": "veg",
            "price": "20"
      }
   ]
}
```

Can anyone please look into it and help me figure out how to use it i have tried using `{{key.replace(new RegExp(' ')}}` in place of `{{key}}` to replace space but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding the field name with UTF8 code
`'\u0022Veg Starters\u0022'`